# what does erase word/cmd/env in texstudio do?

Tags: texstudio

It is in the idefix menu, but I was not able to figure out what it does. I tried looking at the manual, but it only states that it exists, and does not explain.

Answer (score 2):

Put the cursor in middle of a command, for example `\al|pha` (`|` represents the cursor) and press `Alt+del` . What happens? The command should be deleted.

Try later with commands with arguments, like `\tild|e{a}`.

Answer (score 2):

In my experiment:

1. If the cursor is on or next to a word, the word is deleted.
2. If the cursor is on or next to a command, the command name is deleted (along with the backslash, if the command is known to the command completion system of TeXStudio).
3. If the cursor is on or next `\begin` or `\end`, the corresponding `\begin{...}` and `\end{...}` parts will be deleted (not the environment's content).

Comment: I'm using TeXstudio 2.12.6 and the backslash is also deleted in case 2.

Comment: @Sigur 2.12.6 also for me. I confirm no removing of the backslash. Maybe it depends on the OS.

Comment: I'm using Linux Mint 18. I don't remember if I set up something. Let me see.

Comment: Looks like if the command is known to TeXstudio's autocompletion, the backslash is deleted. If it is unknown, the backslash is not deleted. So for example with `\foo` the backslash remains, with `\bar` the backslash is deleted. (@Sigur)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I added the info, indeed I tested with a file full of  commands defined in various ways to see which ones are marked by TeXStudio as “wrong”.